# Ajax load content scroll Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

Content is not loaded. Throws such an error https://prnt.sc/ruorh8-00-00
During scrolling loading ... appears, but then always displays alert

server not responding

what can be done ?

please help.

it's scroll but doesnt show and get content scroll time. In the console -> network show this (screen)

search.blade.php

```
search.blade.php 

    @extends('layouts.app')

    @section('content')

    @if(isset($details))

    <div class="container news-row">
        <div class="row news-small-row">
            @forelse ($details as $article_found)
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <?php echo $article_found->title ?>
                </div>

            @empty
                <h2 class="text-center">Empty</h2>
            @endforelse
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="pagination-container">
          <ul class="pagination">
            {{$details->links()}}
          </ul>
        </div> -->

    </div>
    <div class="ajax-load text-center" style="display:none">
    <p>Loading...</p>
    </div>
@else
  <h3 >Empty</h3>
@endif

@endsection
```

app.js

```
  var page = 1;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {
      page++;
      loadMoreData(page);
    }
  });
  function loadMoreData(page){

    alert();
     $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
    });
    $.ajax({
      method: 'GET', 
      url: '?page=' + page,
      type: "get",
      datatype: "json",
      cache: false,

      beforeSend: function(){
        alert();
        $('.ajax-load').show();
      }
    })
    .done(function(data){
      if(data.html == " "){
      $('.ajax-load').html("No more records found");
      return;
    }
      $('.ajax-load').hide();
      $("#post-data").append(data.html);
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
     alert('server not responding...');
    });
  }
```

web.php

```
Route::any('/search',function(Request $request){
    $q = Input::get ( 'q' );
    $article_found = Article::where('meta_keyword','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')->paginate(5);
    if ($request->ajax()) {
      $view = view('data',compact('article_found'))->render();
      return response()->json(['html'=>$view]);
    }
        return view('blog.search')->withDetails($article_found)->with('details',$article_found)->withQuery ( $q );
});
```

Comment: But here's a big problem with ajax queries, and what the problem is ?

Comment: Let's start with the fact that it displays a compilation error for me

Comment: are you sure this error is for ajax? i think its your template error, if i am not wrong you are using twig?

Comment: @AhmedSunny    i use blade

Comment: js code  does not give you compile error, so its your blade code that giving your error here.

Comment: @AhmedSunny I understood this, so it would have to be fixed

Comment: `<div class="ajax-load text-center" style="display:none">`  this misses a closing tag like '</div>' ,

Comment: @AhmedSunny Yes, i add this closing tag. and add `section script` . please watch my answer , i update it. In this moment in console error not showing , but doesnt work. If i remove  `section script` loading block shows up and then disappears but get console error `$ undefined`.
When i add `section script` than error not , but  nothing works

Comment: the problem of $ undefined is your code is loaded before jquery is loaded, either put your script code in a js file and load it after jquery loads, or load jquery before loading content.

Comment: @AhmedSunny I add all my js code in the app.js. compile webpack and in this moment that error is remove, but i want to load content in scroll time  , but it doesnt do ... Please help

Comment: @AhmedSunny it's return me `server not responding`

Comment: server not responding is your custom error  which you alert on ajax fail. open console, goto network tab, then XHR, and then reload it, you will see you ajax request with error, and when you click on request, you will see response with actual error

Comment: `message: "View [data] not found."
exception: "InvalidArgumentException"
file: "C:\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder.php"
line: 137`
I get this error

Comment: @AhmedSunny it ge me that error https://prnt.sc/ruorh8

Comment: @NikitaKurilovic so you are writing the entire logic on Route itself ?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz yes

Comment: So why there is a need of MVC when you are not using **C**ontroller ?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz Well this time I wrote in web.php

Comment: Did you find some solution ?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz no . i didnt find it :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211145/discussion-between-mayank-pandeyz-and-nikita-kurilovic).